# I want a program that writes every possible combination to a different line of a text file

Tags: python, recursion

I want to write a program that would print every combination of a set of variables to a text file, creating a word list. Each answer should be written on a separate line and write all of the results for 1 digit, 2 digits, and 3 digits to a single text file.

Is there a simple way I can write a python program that can accomplish this? Here is an example of the output I am expecting when printing all the binary number combinations possible for 1, 2, and 3 digits:

```
Output:
0  
1

00  
01  
10  
11

000  
001  
010  
011  
100  
101  
110  
111
```

Comment: first of all this is super easy if you have any programming experience at all. secondly, why would you even want to do this? I can't think of any good reason for it at all. Perhaps if you tell us why, we can help steer you better.

Comment: I have no programming experience other than understanding of the basic concepts behind it.  This is mostly for the sake of my own curiosity to help me understand programming better from a theoretical point of view.

Comment: This is definitely not the way to gain better understanding of the theoretical concepts of programming. If you want to do that, read some books, search the web and try to solve the problem on your own. It seems to me that you just want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Does your teacher allow you to use python 2.6 or 3.0? If yes, the standard library comes to the rescue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A naïve solution which solves the problem and is general enough for any application you might have is this:

```
def combinations(words, length):
    if length == 0:
        return []
    result = [[word] for word in words]
    while length > 1:
        new_result = []
        for combo in result:
            new_result.extend(combo + [word] for word in words)
        result = new_result[:]
        length -= 1
    return result
```

Basically, this gradually builds up a tree in memory of all the combinations, and then returns them. It is memory-intensive, however, and so is impractical for large-scale combinations.

Another solution for the problem is, indeed, to use counting, but then to transform the numbers generated into a list of words from the wordlist. To do so, we first need a function (called `number_to_list()`):

```
def number_to_list(number, words):
    list_out = []
    while number:
        list_out = [number % len(words)] + list_out
        number = number // len(words)
    return [words[n] for n in list_out]
```

This is, in fact, a system for converting decimal numbers to other bases. We then write the counting function; this is relatively simple, and will make up the core of the application:

```
def combinations(words, length):
    numbers = xrange(len(words)**length)
    for number in numbers:
        combo = number_to_list(number, words)
        if len(combo) < length:
            combo = [words[0]] * (length - len(combo)) + combo
        yield combo
```

This is a Python generator; making it a generator allows it to use up less RAM. There is a little work to be done after turning the number into a list of words; this is because these lists will need padding so that they are at the requested length. It would be used like this:

```
>>> list(combinations('01', 3))
[['0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '1'],
['0', '1', '0'], ['0', '1', '1'],
['1', '0', '0'], ['1', '0', '1'],
['1', '1', '0'], ['1', '1', '1']]
```

As you can see, you get back a list of lists. Each of these sub-lists contains a sequence of the original words; you might then do something like `map(''.join, list(combinations('01', 3)))` to retrieve the following result:

```
['000', '001', '010', '011', '100', '101', '110', '111']
```

You could then write this to disk; a better idea, however, would be to use the built-in optimizations that generators have and do something like this:

```
fileout = open('filename.txt', 'w')
fileout.writelines(
    ''.join(combo) for combo in combinations('01', 3))
fileout.close()
```

This will only use as much RAM as necessary (enough to store one combination). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

```
# Given two lists of strings, return a list of all ways to concatenate
# one from each.
def combos(xs, ys):
    return [x + y for x in xs for y in ys]

digits = ['0', '1']
for c in combos(digits, combos(digits, digits)):
    print c

#. 000
#. 001
#. 010
#. 011
#. 100
#. 101
#. 110
#. 111
```

Comment: This gets storage intensive if the sets are large - but you can probably effectively argue that storage to disk gets expensive at the same time.

Comment: There's probably a way to address that with a generator comprehension in place of the list comprehension, but that'd require making a copy of the input iterator. (You can only go through an iterator once. Dang Python for not being Haskell!)

Comment: So instead I'd write the obvious recursive code with no generators.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't be too hard in most languages.  Does the following pseudo-code help?

```
for(int i=0; i < 2^digits; i++)
{
     WriteLine(ToBinaryString(i));
}
```

Comment: That works for binary digit strings - and can probably be made to work for most digit strings.  It won't easily adapt to more arbitrary things, such as a set of words.

Comment: If you treat each word of set as an digit in an n-base number system,
it'll work.

Answer (score 2):

A basic function to produce all the permutations of a list is given below. In this approach, permutations are created lazily by using generators.

```
def perms(seq):
    if seq == []:
        yield []
    else:
        res = []
        for index,item in enumerate(seq):
            rest = seq[:index] + seq[index+1:]
            for restperm in perms(rest):
                yield [item] + restperm

alist = [1,1,0]
for permuation in perms(alist):
    print permuation
```

Comment: Did you intend to use [1,1,0] instead of just [1,0]?  If so, please explain.

Comment: The question seems to be about powersets, not permutations. This code produces n! results, not 2**n results.